# How do I construct a new object from a Smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

What I want to do is this:

```
{myfunc myattribute=new MyClass('arg1', 'arg2')}
```

But it gives me an error when I try, saying that the function MyClass isn't defined.

The work-around I've been using is to create a top level function like this:

```
function MyClass($arg1, $arg2) { return new MyClass($arg1, $arg2); }
```

Then in the template doing:

```
{myfunc myattribute=MyClass('arg1', 'arg2')}
```

But is there anyway to avoid creating a new top level function for every class that I want contrastable from Smarty?

I guess I could also create a function that just takes the name of a class to let me construct any class, but that's kind of an ugly solution.

Edit:
To everyone telling my violating best practices, perhaps this will make you feel better:

The object I'm constructing is a widget to render some html. The actual code looks like:

```
{render_widget widget=new MyWidget() id="myid" name="myname"}
```

Also, I'm unfortunately currently stuck on PHP 5.2, so I cannot use closures. I can use the latest version of Smarty3, though I'm currently using a version of Smarty 3.0.

Comment: So you're trying to create a class in smarty? You must be doing something wrong. Smarty should only hold html (and smarty variables of course). With a very few exceptions. You know you can just pass an object to smarty and use it there right? Or have I misread the question?

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.smarty.net/best_practices

1. Do not embed PHP
2. Keep PHP constructs separate
3. Keep business logic separate

In your case you mix presentation logic with business logic - and it is bad.

However, you can write your custom Smarty plugin (wrapper) for custom objects creation - and (I think) that it is more appropriate "Smarty-way" solution.

See http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.tpl and http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.functions.tpl

For example.

Definition:

```
function smarty_function_custom_class($params, &$smarty)
{
    $class = $params['class'];       
    $smarty->assign($params['var'], new $class());  
}
```

Usage:

```
{custom_class var='myObject' class='MyClass'}
```

---

**Update**

So, if you have such construction:

```
{render_widget widget=new MyWidget() id="myid" name="myname"}
```

You can change your `render_widget` in this way:

```
function smarty_function_render_widget($params, &$smarty)
{
    $class = $params['widget'];       

    $id = $params['id'];
    $name = $params['name'];

    $widget = new $class($id, $name);

    /**
     *  if you need object in your template, assign it to same variable:
     */
    $smarty->assign($params['widget'], $widget);
    // rest of your code    
}
```

And after that you can use it in this way:

```
{render_widget widget="MyWidget" id="myid" name="myname"}
```

Comment: No, the object I want to create is purely a presentation object. I already have a custom smarty function, and I'm trying to construct an object to pass to it.

Comment: Also I don't want to assign it to a variable, in the current scope, I want to pass it as a parameter to the custom smarty function I already have. Having to bind it to a variable first would work I guess but it strikes me as ugly.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)?

```
{myfunc myattribute=function() { return new MyClass('arg1', 'arg2'); }}
```

It's not the prettiest thing ever, but it should get the job done. (As a side note, you may want to consider switching to the [PHP Templating language](http://phptemplatinglanguage.com/) sometime in the future)

Comment: Good answer, but I'm stuck on PHP 5.2, I updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm seriously mis-reading the question you are going about it the wrong way. Smarty should only hold html and the smarty variables (with very few exceptions). You'll want to write your class in    PHP and instantiate an object there and pass that to smarty. Here's an example:

Php:

```
class Class_name
{
    private $int;

    public function funtion_name()
    {
        $this->int = 1;
        return $this->int;
    }
}

//instantiate the object  

$obj = new Class_name();

$smarty->('smarty_variable_name', $obj);
```

Smarty:

```
$smarty_variable_name->funtion_name()}
```

This should output 1.

Also bear with me, I wrote this on my phone :(

Comment: The object I want to construct is a widget, and the custom smarty function I'm trying to pass it to renders it.